# htaccess: Combining rules causes too many redirects

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Combining rules to remove www. and add https (universally), like so

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Results in a blank page stating 'too many redirects occurred' and 'will never open'.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Sometimes `%{HTTPS} off` doesn't work with some servers.

Comment: Try changing that to `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443`

Comment: @anubhava I used `%{SERVER_PORT} 80` and it worked. Please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes this condition `%{HTTPS} off` doesn't work with some servers.

Change that condition to `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80` like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```